# ¿Como convertir lista de listas en lista?

Tags: lista, haskell

En `Haskell`, tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
[[17,16,15],[14,13,12],[11,10,9],[8,7,6],[5,4,3],[2,1]]
```

Y me gustaría obtener

```
[17,16,14,13,11,10,8,7,5,4,2,1]
```

Es decir: de cada 3-tupla, eliminar la última componente. Y si la tupla, posee menos elementos, no eliminar ninguno, como se ve en el ejemplo.

Pongo otro caso, por si no me he explicado bien.

```
[[10,9,7],[7,5,5],[4,3,1],[0]] --> [10,9,7,5,4,3,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas combinar por un lado una función que extraiga los dos primeros elementos, tan fácil como hacer una *mapeo* `map (take 2)`. Por otro lado, necesitas la concatenación de resultados con `concat`. Como es tan común combinar un `map` y un `concat`, existe en `Data.List` una combinación de ambos llamada `concatMap`:

```
import Data.List (concatMap)

f :: [[a]] -> [a]
f = concatMap (take 2)
```